# how to get the string until meeting some specific string at the end in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match the result by regular expression in javascript.
My requirement is to match the string until at the end of some specific string, for example:
if the end of the specific string is endof1 or endof2, then in
`abcendof1`, `cdeendof2`, the matched result will be `abc`, or `cde`.

How to write the regex?

Comment: Why does it have to be regex, why can't you just do: `"abcendof1".split("endof1").shift()` ?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a regex replace:

```js
var str = "abcendof1";
str = str.replace(/^(.*)endof1$/, "$1")
console.log(str);
```

This answer has the behavior that should the string not match, the entire input string would be returned.  I assume you would be able to handle this logic as you see fit.